# Registration form not submitting using Django 1.6

Tags: python, django

So I am having a problem with my registration form. As When the user sign's up, it adds the user to the database with email, password and username (I see the new user within the admin interface) But, when they get sent to the next step of registering their other information as I press submit to move to the next step, it will not allow me move on, it simply erases the information on the form with submitting it. I have been stuck on this for a few days, so any help would be appreciated!

Below is my forms.py with my signup and register forms. And my Views.py with my signup and registration views

EDIT======

Just updated my views.py register definition and my template, and I am still getting the same thing to happen. It is just clearing the form out and not saving the data or preceding on to the next page.

**forms.py:**

```
###### Signup for users ###########
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'required':True}))
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username','required':True}))
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    password2=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Re-Enter Password','required':True}))


    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields from User model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if not username:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter a username.")
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username already exist")
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if not email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter an email.")
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email already exist")
        return email


    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if not password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")

        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")

        return password2



###### Registration for users ###########
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    real_name=forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Real Name','required':True}))
    birthday=forms.DateField(label=_(u"birthdate(mm/dd/yy)"),widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, now[0]+1)),required=False)
    city=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'City','required':True}))
    state=forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'State','required':True}))
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields from User model and the extension of the user model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        model = ProfileUser
        fields = ['real_name', 'birthday','city','state','image']
    def save(self):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.real_name = self.cleaned_data['real_name']
        user.birthday = self.cleaned_data['birthday']
        user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        user.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        user.image = self.cleaned_data['image']
        if commit:
           user.save()

         return user
```

**Views.py:**

```
###### Signup for users ###########
def signup(request):
    template_var={}
    form = SignupForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=SignupForm(request.POST.copy())
        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email=form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password=form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user=User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("register")
    template_var["form"]=form
    return render_to_response("registration/signup.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

###### Registration for users ###########
def register(request):
form=RegisterForm()
template_var={}
template_var["form"]=form
if request.method=="POST" and form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(request)
    form=RegisterForm(request.POST.copy(),request.FILES)
    form.save()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        save(request, user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))    
return render_to_response("registration/register.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Template**

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Settings -Indieitude{% endblock title %}

<!-- Main content of images -->
{% block search %}
{% endblock search %}

{% block space %}
<div  class="space-registration"></div>
{% endblock space %}


{% block settings %}
<section id="content">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="inner width-2">
            <h1 class="heading-title" align="center">Register Below</h1>
            <div class="msg-alert"></div>
                <div class="form-submit center">
                    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                        <ul>
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" >
                             {{form.as_table}}        
                          </table>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="mleft"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="SAVE" class="button large size2 bold"/></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
{% endblock settings %}
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    user_title = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name="Influencer Level", blank=True)
    user_points = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name="Style Points", blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images',null=True, blank=True)


    #admin level and additional infomation
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Override the _unicode_() method to return out something meaningful
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.real_name, self.birthday, self.city, self.state, self.image, self.user_title, self.user_points)
```

Comment: Right! Just added it!

Comment: your models file? :) There is something fishy with your registration form. You are using it as if it is not a model form at all. Also, you never display any errors in your template. There might be some useful error messages if you replaced your form in the template with `{% form.as_p %}` (just for debugging, but then also see how to display field error and non-field errors in your template afterwards).

Comment: Just added the models file!